# How to read file to string from pub/media directory?

Tags: magento2

I want to read a html file to string that is located in the pub/media directory, how should I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the directory, use `Magento\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList`:

```
$om = \Magento\Core\Model\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$directoryList = $om->get(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::class);

$pubMediaDir = $directoryList->getPath(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
```

In a custom class you will **not instantiate the object manager**, but instead inject `Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList` via `di.xml`, then use it like this:

```
$pubMediaDir = $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
```

To read the file to a string, use the PHP function [\file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file-get-contents)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a different way to the way above. Using magentos in built classses rather than raw php

```
   public  function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File $driverFile,
    LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->directoryList =$directoryList;
    $this->driverFile = $driverFile;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

    public function getFileContents($fileName) {
    $paths = [];
    try {
        //get the base folder path you want to scan (replace var with pub / media or any other core folder)
        $path = $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA).$fileName ;
        //read just that single directory
        $contents =  $this->driverFile->fileGetContents($path);
    } catch (FileSystemException $e) {
        $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $contents;
}
```